# c++ recursive call not pushing item to vector

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

A few days ago, I asked a VERY similar question to the one I am about to ask about recursion. Here is the link to the old question:[C++ vector loses data in recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9331404/1216527)

I feel pretty dense right about now, because I thought I understood the problem with trying to push to a vector in a recursive call, but I am now having issues with a similar function.
Here is the bit of code for the function:

```
void TriangleDynamic::collectRayRecursive(Ray &ray, double binSize, double radius, Point &org)
{   
    if (getLowestLevel())
    {
        //this is where I push the ray. 
        raysPushBack(move(ray));
    }

    else
    {
        bool foundIntersectSub = false;
        unsigned int ctr = 0;
        while((!foundIntersectSub) && (ctr<=getSubTrianglesSize() - 1 ))
        {
            if (getSubTriangle(ctr).intersect(ray) )
            {
                foundIntersectSub = true;
                getSubTriangle(ctr).collectRayRecursive(ray, binSize, radius, org);

            }
            ctr = ctr + 1;
        }
    }

}
```

The function is part of the TriangleDynamic class and takes a Ray as a parameter. The Ray is known to intersect with the TriangleDynamic object, but if the triangle is not the "lowest level" triangle, the function looks through the triangles subTriangles to find which subTriangle has also been intersected by the Ray (one will be intersected by design). This is where the recursive call occurs, and it is only once the lowest level triangle is reached that a ray will be pushed to the vector which is called rays and is member data of TriangleDynamic. But once again I lose data. Is there any way of doing this? I can't believe how quickly and easily my previous question was answered, I thought I would try again! Thanks!

Comment: Where does your rays vector live?

Comment: Within the TriangleDynamic as member data.

Comment: I added it after I posted this originally, but it's a vector that holds Ray objects.

Comment: Is `move` here `std::move` ? Show the raysPushBack function. The method signature matters in C++.

Comment: 'move' is 'std::move', and the code for the raysPushBack function is 'void raysPushBack(Ray &ray) {rays.push_back(ray) ;}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getSubTriangle(ctr).collectRayRecursive(ray, binSize, radius, org);
```

Your vector lives in a `TriangleDynamic` [as you said], but your recursive call works on a different instance of a `TriangleDynamic` each time, so the `vector` of the first recursive call is not the same as the vector of the second recursive call, which is not the same as the 3rd recursive call.... [well, I cannot be sure about it realy since I need more code for it, but I assume so].

You will have to make sure that after the recursive call, you copy the `vector` which lives in the Triangle generated by `getSubTriangle()` to `this`.

**EDIT: a peek on the "stack trace" of the recursive invokation:**

The calls stack could look something like that:

```
|triangle_1.collectRayRecursive()|
---------------------------------
```

By invoking the recursive call you get [note that triangle_1, triangle_2 are different objects]

```
|triangle_2.collectRayRecursive()|
|triangle_1.collectRayRecursive()|
---------------------------------
```

And so on: ...

```
|triangle_n.collectRayRecursive()|
....
|triangle_2.collectRayRecursive()|
|triangle_1.collectRayRecursive()|
---------------------------------
```

Now, you modify the `vector` that lives inside the object `triangle_n` [the deepest recursive call], but not the `vector` in the other triangles.

When you get back from the recursion, you pop the head, which is `triangle_n` - without copying the `vector`.

As a result - the new information was not added to the vector in `triangle_(n-1)`, which will not pass it to `triangle_(n-2)` ... which will not pass it to `triangle_1` - where you expect to see the final results.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. I have a couple questions about your answer. When I copy the vector will that create another vector of rays in the higher levels of triangles? I just want the Rays to be stored in the lowest level. Just let me know if you need to see anymore code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1216527: If your vector is actually allocated on the triangle [as value and not by reference]: You will have to store `getSubTriangle()` in a temporary variable [let it be `temp`] and copy `temp.raysVector` [making up name here] to `this.raysVector` after each recursive call. It will make the vector from deepest level to bubble its way down to the first level.

Comment: Hmmm... I still seem to be having problems. I know that I've gotten to the lowest level of the triangle, and I know that I have pushed a ray. But when I create a temp variable of getSubTriangle(ctr) right after the recursive call, the rays vector is empty (nothing to copy). Thank you for your patience, any ideas?

Comment: @user1216527: Create the temp variable [let it be `temp`] **before** the recursive call, and then invoke: `temp.collectRayRecursive(...)`. after the recursive call, collect the `vector` from `temp` into `this`.

Comment: ok. so, before the recursive call I set temp equal to `getSubTriangle(ctr)` then after the recursive call I do this `rays.resize(temp.rays.size());` and then this `copy(temp.rays.begin(), temp.rays.end(), rays.begin());` Still nothing gets permanently put in the vector. Am I still missing the point?

Comment: There is a ray in the upper most triangle, but what I wanted was the ray only in the lowest level triangle. Is this possible?